# convertToFusionCharts second parameter not working?

Tags: jquery, charts, fusioncharts

I having problems with the second parameter in `convertToFusionCharts()`. I'm trying to set caption, useLabels, major or anything, but without results, in the site eg. also seem to have problems.

It's set to show a caption ("Units sold for last 2 years") but it's not working.

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-javascript-libraries/jquery/rendering-charts-from-html-tables.html

I'm trying:

```
jQuery("#myHTMLTable").convertToFusionCharts(

{
   type: 'MSColumn2D',
   width: "100%",
   height: "500", 
   dataFormat: "htmltable",
   renderAt: "myChartContainer"

},
{

   hideTable: true, 

   useLabels: 0, 

   useLegend: 0,  

   showLegend: false, 

   showLabels: false, 

   major: "row" 

}
);
```

Anyone know what's happing?

Answer (score 0):

try setting them within chartattributes like this:

```
jQuery("#myHTMLTable").convertToFusionCharts({
type: "pie2d",
width: "100%",
height: "650",
dataFormat: "htmltable",
renderAt: "chart-testhtmlid"}, {
"chartAttributes": {
    caption: "Current Db Sizes:",
    xAxisName: "Size (MB)",
    yAxisName: "DB Name",
    exportEnabled : "1",
    exportAtClientSide: "1",
    exportFileName: Instance + " Db Sizes " + ReportDate,
    defaultNumberScale: "MB",
    numberScaleValue: "1000,1000",
    numberScaleUnit: "GB,TB",
        bgColor: "FFFFFF",
        theme: "fint"
},
"ignoreCols": [1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
});
```